# My JavaScript console game is not working

Tags: javascript

This is my first time asking a question here, so pardon if it has an error/is less descriptive.

Actually, I am a beginner in JavaScript, and while making a console guess game, there is just nothing in the output window(it supports alert and prompt boxes). Here's the code:

```js
function runGame() {
  Boolean isPlaying = true;
  var tries = 3;
  var guess = 0;
  var randInt = Math.floor(Math.random(10) * 1);

  alert("You have 3 chances to guess a number between 1 & 10!");

  while (guess != randInt && tries > 0) {
    guess = prompt("Enter a guess between 1 & 10: ");

    if (guess > randInt) {
      tries--;
      alert("Too high!");
    } else if (guess < randInt) {
      tries--;
      alert("Too low!");
    } else {
      alert("Exactly! " + randInt + " it is! You've won!");
    }
  }

  if (tries < 1) {
    isPlaying = false;
  }
}

while (isPlaying == true) {
  runGame();
}
```

Comment: There is nothing like this `Boolean isPlaying = true;` in javascript.

Comment: You don't have to assign the data type of the variable in javascript.

Comment: I think you want this:  var randInt = Math.floor(Math.random(10) * 1); to be  var randInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10); as it is randInt is always zero and you never get to your prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Moved your `while isPlaying` to the inside `while` loop. A while loop with a function inside will just call that function over and over again.

`Math.random(10)` only changes the seed, it does not choose between 1-10.

```js
function runGame() {
  var isPlaying = true;
  var tries = 3;
  var guess = 0;
  var randInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

  alert("You have 3 chances to guess a number between 1 & 10!");

  while (guess != randInt && tries > 0 && isPlaying) {

    guess = prompt("Enter a guess between 1 & 10: ");

    if (guess > randInt) {
      tries--;
      alert("Too high!");
    } else if (guess < randInt) {
      tries--;
      alert("Too low!");
    } else {
      alert("Exactly! " + randInt + " it is! You've won!");
    }
  }

  if (tries < 1) {
    isPlaying = false;
  }
}

runGame()
```